# Delete option for answer does not appear automatically after downvote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I attempted to delete an answer that was irrelevant to its question. There was no delete option visible (I have enough reputation for the privilege to delete answers). I downvoted the answer, changing its vote from 0 to -1. The delete option did not appear. I refreshed the page, the delete option did appear and I could vote to delete the answer.

I expected the delete option to appear when the question was downvoted into the negative -- is not showing the delete option immediately a bug or is the system operating as designed?

Comment: it's designed to work that way. For answers and questions.

Comment: As I recall delete votes require a - 3 count

Comment: It's more complicated from that. Delete votes for answers require a negative score (unless they are being cast from the Low Quality Posts review queue, in which case they require a nonpositive score). Delete votes for several-day-old closed questions can be cast regardless of the score. Delete votes for recently-closed questions require a -3 score.

Comment: This appears to be [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. There's a feature request to add this from 2011 on Meta Stack Exchange: [Option to delete an answer only visible after a reload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115702/option-to-delete-an-answer-only-visible-after-a-reload). The userscript [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) adds this capability and a substantial number of other improvements/changes.

Comment: I was told that there were not that many users that would benefit from this feature, so they didn't bother do to a real time refresh. Same thing for close votes. But your "thanks" vote will be seen in real time!

Comment: This is only an issue when there is a vote threshold for deletion, your downvote causes the vote count to cross that threshold, and you have the delete privilege. So it doesn't happen very often. There is a readily available workaround (refresh the page). I'd rather have developer time spent on more widely applicable improvements. (Related: If you upvote so that the question no longer qualifies for deletion, should the "delete" option be removed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you were using is not part of the Stack Exchange software, but was provided by a user script, most likely the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) (SOUP) user script. (That script's [feature list](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CONTENTS.md) lists this as one of the things it adds.)

If you're not able to use the feature, check to see if that script (or another script) is activated and running correctly. If it's still not working, you should file a bug report with the author of the script.